# Layout with 4 square buttons equally spaced and scale based on width of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Is there a way to have a layout with the 4 square buttons. The buttons should scale based on the width of the screen. I might have come across some ways of doing this dynamically in code, but is there a way to do it in the xml layout directly?

[image]

I'm new to the new ConstraintLayout in Android, but if it is possible using that, I'd appreciate being pointed to in the right direction to try it out. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about ContraintLayout, but for sure you can do it using a RelativeLayout. Therefore, I guess you could use a ConstraintLayout as well. Another solution which comes to mind is using a 2x2 GridView.

Comment: You can use weight sum for that which is perfectly fit in every devices.

Comment: I've tried grid view as well as relative layout, but the problem is keeping the buttons square

Comment: Did you tried with Linear layout?

Comment: Same problem. I guess I have to use code to dynamically size it

Comment: No. Linear layout definitely solve your problem. Just put different layouts for different screen.

Comment: To keep the buttons square, just give them the same size for both width and height. In **dp**s, obviously. RelativeLayouts work very well, with the "dummy View" trick.

Answer (score 1):

**Take a look on these**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Button 3"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Button 4"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Create different values folder (like values-small, values-large) and create dimens.xml file in appropriate folder put size (like 100dp for small) and use it where I used 150dp for button size.[image: buttons_with_linear]

Comment: Nested weights (and nested layouts in general) are bad for performances.

Comment: Suggestions always appreciated... Any good solution @Rotwang for nested weights? Really Thanks...

Comment: The PercentRelativeLayout is designed to solve this problem

Comment: @Abhishek, thanks for your solution. Besides nested layouts, i'll also have to set different dimensions for different sizes. I was trying to keep the solution within a static xml layout, but possibly the easier solution is by checking the dimensions in code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_weight` this can divide the size of layout as you want

Comment: Someone already answered so. See why it's not a good practice in the comments.

Comment: OK, from next time I will add these type of answers in comment

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the solution with ConstraintLayout. The other layouts had some element missing which would have forced me to use code to dynamically check the screen width and make calculations.

Some of the points/steps to note are:

- I used a set of 4 vertical guidelines against which I could constrain the buttons
- A middle (invisible) view to constrain the lower two buttons from the top
- 1 horizontal guideline to set the horizontal placement in the screen. I wasn't able to set the middle view baselined to the guideline (maybe this is not possible), but had to set the top of the view to the guideline.
- set the layout_constraintDimensionRatio of all the buttons to 1

Hope this helps someone. I've posted the images and code below:

[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.90"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="528dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.60"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="324dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.40"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="276dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="72dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonMiddle"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline5"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonMiddle"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonMiddle"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonMiddle"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMiddle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

ConstraintLayout seems quite powerful, and there may be other ways to do it as well.