# create side by side images from RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

i am trying to add 4 images, of half of the width of mobile screen device size with left right margin.

Here i am using a layout as `RelativeLayout` where i want to create a grid view sort of view. Here is how my layout should look like:

[image]

Here is how i am trying to show the layout view in android XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/li_profile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative1_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/lamp"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/lamp"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative1_profile"
        android:id="@+id/relative1_profile1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/lamp"
            android:id="@+id/profile_image3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/lamp"
            android:id="@+id/profile_image4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

as per the above code we are trying to add this view in a ViewPager so it can swipable.

To make it consistent with different screen sizes we have added some dynamic margin to external `@+id/relative1_profile`.

Any suggestions related to this will be helpful to understand. We tried working with `GridView` as well, but then the "brown" image is not displaying well in all the mobile resolutions.

Thank you! (in advance)

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/44257903/5726600

Comment: As per your requirement i will personally suggest you to use CardView and Recycler View By using material design.
here is tutorial link let me know if i can help you.

https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Android grid example using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager (like the old GridView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the)

Comment: @MikeSpeed how will i place a image on top of three images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worst coding is done,but you can acheieve it.

Better to go with LinearLayout and add weights,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="#ccc"
          />
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="#000"
          />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="#2529a3"
          />
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="#318339"
          />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:weightSum="2"
        >


      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="end"
          android:elevation="@dimen/dimen5"
          android:layout_marginStart="-50dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="#746e6e"
          />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          />
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The screenshot is provided below.

[image]

Comment: But i want one of the image to be overlapping on other 3 images.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the new ConstraintLayout, by adding guides on percentages of the screen and specifying ratios for each content.

Add it to your gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

And then simply make the ConstraintLayout parent view.
If you want one to overlap, simply add a vertical guide to 50% of the screen and another horizontal guide to 50% of the screen, giving you four equally spaced squares. To make the last square overlap, you can add a third and fourth guide (horizontal/vertical) to 40%/60% of the screen, and constraining the last square to it.